# How can different branches of a primary repo use different branches of submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Suppose that I have a primary repo `y` with some submodule, say at `sub/x`.

Suppose also that, for both the primary and the submodule repos, `master` is the active branch, and that the `.gitmodules` file of the primary repo specifies `branch = master`.

Now, suppose that, in addition to its `master` branch, the primary (`y`) repo has a branch `yA`, and likewise, in addition to *its* `master` branch, the submodule repo (`x`) has a branch `xA`.

I would like the `yA` branch of the `y` repo to "see"/use the `xA` branch of the `x` repo.

This would mean that switching between the `master` and `yA` branches in the primary repo would cause the corresponding switch between the `master` and `xA` branches in the submodule.

Does git have any support for this?

---

I tried the following:

1. switched to the `yA` branch on the primary repo;
2. switched to the `xA` branch on the submodule repo;
3. replaced `master` with `xA` as the value for the branch parameter in the primary repo's `.gitmodules` file;
4. in the primary repo, committed all the changes resulting from (2) and (3).

This did not work as I had hoped: if I switch to the `master` branch on the primary repo, this has no effect on the active branch setting of the submodule repo (and therefore, the `master` branch does not have a clean status).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1777854/2864740 -?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does git have any support for [what I want]?

Sort of, I think.  You will need to make sure that `.git/modules` (in the superproject) *does not* acquire a setting.

#### TL;DR

Use different settings in `.gitmodules` (in the superproject commits), and use `git submodule update --remote` as needed.  I have not tested this, but see the long description.

#### Long

My overall general advice: the `branch` setting of a submodule is mostly useless and irrelevant.  Just ignore it.  We'll get to the *mostly* part in a bit, though, and you can see if you can use it.

A submodule is defined as a Git repository in which some *other* Git will, on occasion, enter into that submodule and run some Git command.  The other Git is called the superproject.

The superproject Git's main operation is:

```
(cd $path && git checkout $hash)
```

Nowhere in this sequence does any branch name occur.  That's *why* the `branch` setting is irrelevant.

The `$path` and `$hash` parts come from the superproject Git's *index*, and they got there by being extracted from a commit in the superproject.  That commit recorded the path of the submodule, and a raw hash ID.  No branch name occurs here either.

When you run `git checkout` or `git switch` in the superproject, to select some branch name and therefore some particular commit, the superproject Git extracts that commit to its (the superproject's) index and to your work-tree for that superproject.  This puts the correct ($path, $hash) pair into the superproject's index.

Unfortunately, it *does not* invoke the `$(cd $path && git checkout $hash)` part by default, to update the submodule.  To make it do so, you have several options:

- Run `git submodule update`.  This command does exactly that (well, by default anyway: see details below).
- Run `git checkout --recurse-submodules` (or the same flag for `git switch`).  This command makes `git checkout` run the update, *and* propagates into the submodule Git, so that when that submodule runs `git checkout` (or `git switch`), if the submodule is a superproject for another submodule, that submodule will, in its superproject role, invoke the update.  This will repeat (recursively) for all nested submodules.  (I generally don't use this but I have not had to deal with recursive submodules much.  It's quite powerful, because of the recursion.)
- Set `submodule.recurse` to true.  This enables the `--recurse-submodules` option on multiple commands, including checkout/switch, but also on `git fetch` and `git pull`.  (I dislike this one: I think it's *too* powerful.  However, you can set it, and then explicitly disable recursive push with the `push.recurseSubmodules` setting.)

#### Details, or, when *does* the `branch` setting matter?

[The `git submodule` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) has several long and fairly impenetrable paragraphs to describe the `git submodule update` sub-command.  (I believe this indicates a flaw in the overall setup of submodules, but we must work with what we have, at least until we can come up with something better.)  Let me quote from it here:

> `update [--init] [--remote] [-N|--no-fetch] [--[no-]recommend-shallow] [-f|--force] [--checkout|--rebase|--merge] [--reference <repository>] [--depth <depth>] [--recursive] [--jobs <n>] [--[no-]single-branch] [--] [<path>...​]`
> Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject expects by cloning missing submodules, fetching missing commits in submodules and updating the working tree of the submodules. The "updating" can be done in several ways depending on command line options and the value of `submodule.<name>.update` configuration variable. ...

As you can see, there are many options.  To keep this answer from getting even longer, let's concentrate on just three of them: `--checkout`, `--rebase`, and `--merge`.  There are two more that *aren't* options but that you can set with the `submodule.name.update` variable, which we'll ignore here.  These options—`--checkout`, `--rebase`, and `--merge`—set which kind of action the update will use, which is the same as the option name without the leading double hyphen.

The `checkout` mode is the default default.  That is, if you have not set an explicit `submodule.name.update` setting, and you don't specify `--rebase` or `--merge`, you get `checkout`.  So that's what everyone uses—mostly!  So that's what the word *mostly* is doing in the overall general advice at the top of this answer.

Now, on to the three modes.  I'll quote from the documentation again, with some minor formatting changes and commentary afterward:

> - `checkout`
>   the commit recorded in the superproject will be checked out in the submodule on a detached HEAD.
> - `rebase`
>   the current branch of the submodule will be rebased onto the commit recorded in the superproject.
> - `merge`
>   the commit recorded in the superproject will be merged into the current branch in the submodule.

So, with the default mode, no branch name enters the picture anywhere.  Only the `rebase` and `merge` modes actually make use of a branch name.  So now we get to ask the question: *which branch name?*

The documentation makes it clear: *the current branch in the submodule*.  That's not the `branch =` setting *of* the submodule; it's the *current branch **in** the submodule*.

But what branch is current, in the submodule?  You can *find out*, if you like:

```
(cd $path && git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

will tell you, for each path you pass in, what branch if any is current.  It prints `HEAD` if the submodule is using detached-HEAD mode, as it will be if you've run `git submodule update --checkout`, or any `git submodule update` that uses `checkout` mode.

If you were to predict the current branch, or whether the submodule is on a detached HEAD and therefore on any branch at all, what would you predict?  Well, have you run `git submodule update`?  You had to do a `git submodule update --init` initially, unless you did a recursive mode checkout, in which case Git did a `git submodule update --init --checkout` for you.  So chances are that your submodule is in detached-HEAD mode, and therefore has no current branch.

We're still a bit at sea, in other words.  How do we get the submodule Git to be on a branch in the first place?

There's one simple and obvious method: we can do our own `(cd $path; git checkout $branch)` where we provide the `$path` and `$branch` ourselves.  That way, the submodule is on the branch we want, whatever commit that is.  But since *we're* providing `$branch`, we don't need a *setting*.  We just do:

```
(cd path/to/submodule; git checkout feature/foo)
```

directly.  So that's not it either.

If we scroll down to the **OPTIONS** section in the documentation, and then scroll further down to the `--remote` option, we finally find the one place where the setting is actually used:

> `--remote`
> This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch. The remote used is branch’s remote (`branch.<name>.remote`), defaulting to `origin`. The remote branch used defaults to the remote `HEAD`, but the branch name may be overridden by setting the `submodule.<name>.branch` option in either `.gitmodules` or `.git/config` (with `.git/config` taking precedence).
>
> This works for any of the supported update procedures (`--checkout`, `--rebase`, etc.). The only change is the source of the target SHA-1. For example, `submodule update --remote --merge` will merge upstream submodule changes into the submodules, while `submodule update --merge` will merge superproject gitlink changes into the submodules.

[Alllllll-righty then!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tJGk4ofc18)

Seriously, this text is really hard to read—but what it says is that `git submodule update --remote` won't just use the raw SHA-1 hash ID from the superproject.  Instead, it will use a raw SHA-1 hash ID it gets from somewhere else.  Where, precisely, is the somewhere else?

> In order to ensure a current tracking branch state, `update --remote` fetches the submodule’s remote repository before calculating the SHA-1. If you don’t want to fetch, you should use `submodule update --remote --no-fetch`.

So: when you use `--remote` with your `git submodule update` command, the superproject will:

- step 1: `(cd $path; git fetch)`, unless you add `--no-fetch`
- step 2: `(cd $path; git rev-parse $(complicated))` to get a hash ID.

The `$(complicated)` part is complicated, but it grabs the branch name from the `branch =` setting, e.g., `branch = master`, from either `.gitmodules` or `.git/config`.  It turns this into the remote-tracking name, such as `origin/master`, that step 1 will have just updated.  See also [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/1256452) to [How can I specify a branch/tag when adding a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1777854/1256452).

The special name `.` means *use the branch name in the superproject*—but:

> I would like the `yA` branch of the `y` repo to "see"/use the `xA` branch of the `x` repo.

Unless the spellings match exactly, you can't get this with the `.` trick.  And, if the submodule's branch name has been copied into the superproject's `.git/config`, it will stay set to whatever it is set to, but if not, the superproject Git will read the `branch =` setting from the `.gitmodules` file.

If the `.gitmodules` file committed in the primary repository commit `$SHA_YA` as recorded in branch name `yA` says `branch = xA`, then, at the time you run `git submodule update --remote` (with or without `--no-fetch`), the superproject Git should do a `git rev-parse` on `origin/xA`, assuming submodule `x` has `origin` as its remote here.  That will become the source of the raw hash ID that superproject `y` will pass to submodule `x` when superproject `y` runs `(cd x; git checkout $hash)`.

When you switch to some other commit—note that the *branch name* is not relevant here; what matters is the *commit hash ID*, and the `.gitmodules` file that is part of that commit—in the superproject, the `.gitmodules` file in the superproject can have some other `branch =` setting.  Your `git submodule update --remote` command will find *that* setting, and have the submodule Git do a different `git rev-parse` to get the hash ID to pass to the submodule Git when the superproject tells the submodule what to check out.

It is all *very* complicated, with a lot of moving parts.  These parts must all line up at the right time.  The superproject is ultimately really just using raw hash IDs.  It's less head-ache-invoking to just use the right raw hash IDs.  Once they're in a commit, they cannot be changed, and that's normally the right thing, so you just have to make sure they're correct before you commit.

Comment: Thank you.  That was an awe-inspiring answer.  As read it I kept thinking, how could someone other than the programmers who wrote the code know all this stuff???  Short of studying the source code for several weeks I don't see how *I* could have found all this stuff out, and I'm not sure I would have gotten this far even with that.

Comment: @kjo: Submodules are kind of a weak point of both Git and Mercurial. But figuring out the "right behavior" is hard, even for several simplified use cases, and actual use cases tend not to be simple. I haven't come up with anything better myself, I just realize that what we have is ... not good. :-) This stuff used to be a little easier to read as the submodule code is only now being converted from shell scripts to C code, but the shell scripts themselves are messy and invoke a helper that makes reading the code really hard.